# Unicode character not correctly redisplayed in request query string

Tags: jsf, unicode, query-string

I wrote this little JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>What's your Name?</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>What's your name?</h1>
        <h:form>
            <p>Name: <h:inputText value="#{nameController.name}" /></p>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{nameController.process}" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The `name` property in `nameController` is simple, with a variable (of type `String`), a getter, and a setter, just how you would expect. `nameController.process` passes `name` as a GET parameter to another JSF page.

But, if I type "ëlmer" as the name, for example, I am redirected to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/NameThing/name.jsf?name=Ã«lmer
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:8080/NameThing/name.jsf?name=ëlmer
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: This is a character encoding problem.  The output is UTF-8 encoded but is being interpreted somewhere as ISO-8859-1.  Finding out where this is happening will require more information, such as how the redirect is happening, the encoding settings of the response, and possibly examination of the HTTP response stream to determine if it's being misinterpreted before sending or after receipt by the browser.

Comment: You forgot to show code of `process()` method. Cause is most likely in there.

Comment: A URL only supports ASCII characters, you need to use an IRI to use un-encoded Unicode characters like you showed. But in a URL, non-ASCII characters MUST be charset-encoded, such as with UTF-8, and then those octets MUST be url-encoded. `ëlmer` in UTF-8 would be url-encoded as `%C3%ABlmer`, in ISO-8859-1 as `%EBlmer`, etc.